# AngularJS filter multiple words from a string in a single field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Here the idea of my problem :

Imagine, I have an user looking for a book.

As input, he can try to find the book using book title.

Let's take :

```
  $scope.books = ["Heir Of Earth",
    "Woman Of The Solstice",
    "Hunters Of Next Year",
    "Pilots Without Honor",
    "Slaves And A Woman",
    "Kings And Heroes",
    "Decay Of The End",
    "Fortune Of The Land",
    "Rejecting My Dreams",
    "Painting The Angels"];
```

Now I take the user query in a string :

**example :**

```
$scope.userQueryTitle = "Woman Of";
```

I want to get all books which where their title contains "Woman" or "Of" but NOT "Woman" AND "Of".

From there, the corresponding result should be this :

```
$scope.booksResult = ["Heir Of Earth",
"Woman Of The Solstice",
"Hunters Of Next Year",
"Slaves And A Woman",
"Decay Of The End",
"Fortune Of The Land"
];
```

I found some partial solutions to my problem such as use something like :

View:

```
<ul ng-repeat="book in booksResult | filter: getBooksFromTitle">
    <li>{{book}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getBooksFromTitle = function(book){
    return book.match(($scope.userQueryTitle).split(" ")[0]) || 
        book.match(($scope.userQueryTitle).split(" ")[1]);
};
```

It works only if `$scope.userQueryTitle` contains only 2 words but **my problem is** what's about if I have **1** or **4** or **n** word(s) ?

`getBooksFromTitle()` should be flexible about this but I don't see how to deal with...

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can give a try to the following approach...   In your getBooksFromTitle method, You can convert $scope.userQueryTitle to an array and do comparison of two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the getBooksFromTitle function as follows,

```
$scope.getBooksFromTitle = function(book){
    return $scope.books.filter(function(e){ return e.match(new RegExp($scope.query.split(" ").join('|'),'i')) });
};
```

Try to put as many keywords you want, this should solve your problem. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works, I'm just feeling trouble with the fact that I don't understand entirely what this line of code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you:

```
$scope.getBooksFromTitle = function(book){
     var queryWords = $scope.userQueryTitle.split(" ");
     for(var i=0;i<queryWords.length;i++){
         return book.match(queryWords[i]);
     }        
};
```

Comment: No it doesn't work because the function stops when the first `return book.match(queryWords[i]);`  occur. As a result, I get only one result.